# special characters on JSON to xml

Tags: javascript, json, xml, excel

I'm working with Javascript and PHP.

I jave a JSON like this:

```
[{"id": 32, "label": "Some Title", "type": "tinymce", "value": "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵<head>↵</head>↵<body>↵<p>asdasdasda&nbsp;30-09-2017</p>↵</body>↵</html>"}]
```

The real JSON is a loong array of objects/arrays. I'm creating an XML file (with .xls extension) that will be read is Excel. With normal characters everything works correct, but I can't put those special characters in order to get Excel reading that XML file. What can I do?

What can not do is:

- Using another format: I need to read the XML with and .xls extension.
- Change the data from the JSON, it's external.

In the way I'm doing i, tThe XML results in something like this:

```
<ss:Row>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String"></ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String"></ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String"></ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Objeto del contrato</ss:Data>
  </ss:Cell>
  <ss:Cell>
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String"><!DOCTYPE html> // I don't need all the html tags, I just need to put the text of the <p> tags.
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>asdasdasda&nbsp;30-09-2017</p>
</body>
</html></ss:Data>//here ends the wrong text coming from the JSON
  </ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
```

which is not correct for Excel.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to encode HTML chars while parsing from JSON to XML?

Answer (score 1):

Since the contents of the `value` attribute are HTML, you may have a hidden element (or even an element not attached to the DOM), set its `innerHTML` to the contents of this attribute, and then use your favorite DOM-manipulation library (jQuery for instance) to read the contents of the `p` attribute.

For instance, using jQuery:

```
var text = $('<div/>').html(o.value).find('p').text()
```

Alternatively, you could use a regex to match just then contents between `<p>` and `</p>`, though this may be more fragile if the format varies somewhat. In that case, you'll also need to decode HTML entities, which often involves doing much of the same as above.

Comment: I was thinking on use a regex but right, as you say, the content will varies a lot. It comes from a Tinymce editor so it could be anything. I'm thinking on your first option on how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've mentioned in the question that you are using PHP, I'm going to assume that you are processing the JSON in PHP to create the XML file.

In that case, you can use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to query the exact element from the HTML value:

```
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>asdasdasda&nbsp;30-09-2017</p>
</body>
</html>";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '/html/body/p';
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

print $entries->item(0)->nodeValue; //outputs 'asdasdasda 30-09-2017'
```

This assumes that the structure of the HTML will always be the same; if that changes you would need to update your `$query` variable. For example, in order to select all `p` tags in the document, the XPath query would be `//p`.

Comment: I already have something like that with PHPExcel but now I can't do it with PHP. I'm using ReactJS, I'm concatenating some strings that I build in javascript then I'm creating an xml file. The data isn't showed as html on the DOM, it comes from the database from a large JSON but I need just some objects/arrays from it. I have a table which is a list of forms and I'm clickin an "Export to Excel" button on the left column of that table to export the desire form, but I'm not seeing the form itself.